# Text with newline inside a div element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div element

```
<div id="testResult" style="padding-left: 120px;">
```

I am trying to print some text with newline character `'\n'` inside the `div` element.

But in my `html` page displayed text is ignoring the newline character.

```
 $("#testResult").html("Feature: Apply filter to image\n    As an user\n    I want to be able to apply a filter to my image\n    So I can make it look better and match my card's stile\n\n  @US2330 @done\n  Scenario Outline: Apply filter to a picture    # features/card_edit_filter.feature:33\n    Given I am on \"Filters Editor\" screen        # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:1\n    And I see my card with the original image    # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:21\n    When I touch the \"<filter_name>\" filter      # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:1\n    Then I see the image with the filter applied # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:26\n\n    Examples: \n      | filter_name   |\n      | Black & White |\n      | Sepia         |\n      | Vintage       |\n\n  @US2330 @done\n  Scenario: Restore image after applying filter  # features/card_edit_filter.feature:47\n")
```

I want to show the text as:

```
Feature: Apply filter to image
    As an user
    I want to be able to apply a filter to my image
    So I can make it look better and match my card's stile

  @US2330 @done
  Scenario Outline: Apply filter to a picture    # features/card_edit_filter.feature:33
    Given I am on "Filters Editor" screen        # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:1
    And I see my card with the original image    # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:21
    When I touch the "<filter_name>" filter      # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:1
    Then I see the image with the filter applied # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:26

    Examples: 
      | filter_name   |
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Add this css:

```
#testResult
{
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7takw5k/)

Answer (score 15):

You could try a simple css approach maybe?

```
#testResult {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

This will preserve the \n in your output.

Comment: Also worth noting that it will preserve the spaces in the output, which is what OP wants.

Comment: And you can use \t for tabs

Answer (score 2):

`pre-line` is suitable. pre-wrap has extra space before index 0 of the text

```
#testResult {
   white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve newlines and spaces, you can use a `<pre>` element:

```
<pre id="testResult" style="padding-left: 120px;"></pre>

$("#testResult").text("Feature: Apply filter to image\n...e:47\n");
```

Also note the use of `.text()` rather than `.html()`. You should always use `.text()` unless you have a specific reason to need `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a `<pre>` tag

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wmm1jz0/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The syntax below that other friends suggested too, just works when you have hardcoded that string in your component, like this:

```
 var string = "hello\nworld"

 <div>{string}</div>

 //style

 .div {
   white-space: pre-wrap
  }
```

but when you fetch this string from the server (when the string has been added to database in `form-data` format), it is something like:

```
let fetchedString = "hello\\nworld"
```

and that's when the above styling can't extract that `\n`, because it's now known as string.

to solve this, I did the following:

```
var newString = fetchedString.split("\\n").join("\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

in HTML `<br>` is used for new line.. this following code will give your desired result:

```
$("#testResult").html("Feature: Apply filter to image<br>    As an user<br>    I want to be able to apply a filter to my image<br>    So I can make it look better and match my card's stile<br><br>  @US2330 @done<br>  Scenario Outline: Apply filter to a picture    # features/card_edit_filter.feature:33<br>    Given I am on \"Filters Editor\" screen        # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:1<br>    And I see my card with the original image    # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:21<br>    When I touch the \"<filter_name>\" filter      # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:1<br>    Then I see the image with the filter applied # features/step_definitions/card_filter_steps.rb:26<br><br>    Examples: <br>      | filter_name   |<br>      | Black & White |<br>      | Sepia         |<br>      | Vintage       |<br><br>  @US2330 @done<br>  Scenario: Restore image after applying filter  # features/card_edit_filter.feature:47<br>");
```

Comment: To go this route, s/he would also have to replace all the spaces with `&nbsp;`.